# Fluent-NHibernate mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

In my database I have field containg a comma delimited list of emails. How would I map that to a `IList<string>` in my model ?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement an `IUserCollection`, which would map your CSV column to an actual list of emails, then serialize it back on save.

Answer (score 0):

The table in question is not even First Normal Form, which is bad.

The only way you can possibly do that is something along these lines:

```
class Foo
{       
    private List<string> emails = new List<string>();       

    public string _Emails 
    { 
        get { return string.Join(",", emails.ToArray()); }
        set { emails = new List<string>(value.Split(',')); }
    }       

    public IList<string> Emails
    { 
        get { return emails; }          
    }
}
```

and map `_Emails` property.

**Edit**

One more solution is implemention your own `IUserType` or `IUserCollection`. Thus your model will be much prettier.

Comment: Well, sometimes you are not responsible for designing the database.

Your solution will work with some tweaking (the client must be able to add addresses to the Emails field as well), but I was hoping for some kind of user defined mapping. 

Im not very keen on polluting my model :)